# Android Rebound translate up animation

Tags: android, animation

I have popupWindow with some image views, which are created and added progammatically to popup window. Their position is set to bottom line with setY(). But when I use setEndValue to animate with spring, image goes from 0 to setEndValue, not from it's initial position.
How that can be fixed?

```
public SharePostPopupWindow(View parentView) {
        super(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
        this.context = parentView.getContext();
        this.parentView = parentView;

        AndroidBlaBlaApplication.component(context).inject(this);
        setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        FrameLayout container = new FrameLayout(context);

        socialViews = new ArrayList<>();
        socials = new ArrayList<>();

        shadow = new View(context);
        shadow.setId(R.id.share_view_shadow);
        shadow.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        shadow.setClickable(true);
        shadow.setAlpha(0.5f);
        shadow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                bus.post(new ShadowClickedEvent());
                spring.setEndValue(initialPosition / 2 - Utils.convertDpToPixel(imageSize, context));
                dismiss();
            }
        });
}

public void show() {
        Utils.hideKeyboard(context, getContentView());
        createButtons();

        SpringSystem springSystem = SpringSystem.create();
        spring = springSystem.createSpring();

        SpringConfig slowConfig = new SpringConfig(TENSION, DAMPER);
        spring.setSpringConfig(slowConfig);

        spring.addListener(new SimpleSpringListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSpringUpdate(Spring spring) {
                float value = (float) spring.getCurrentValue();

                for (int i = 0; i < socialViews.size(); i++) {
                    if (i % 2 != 0) {
                        socialViews.get(i).setY(value);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        showAtLocation(parentView, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        getContentView().setAlpha(1f);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to force spring animation from certain position, you need to use 
`spring.setCurrentValue` method first.